# Position absolute inside one relative above another relative

Tags: css, html

The question is: is it possible? I have a `div` with `relative position`. Inside this `div`, I have another `div` with `position: absolute` and `top: whatever`.

This absolute positioned `div` overlaps content in parent `div` without any problems, but another relative position div (outside parent) doesn't even care. Before this question I googled as I much as I could, so I'm for 90% sure that it's impossible, or I'm on a wrong way, but I need to be sure.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/MNLbZ/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">11112222233</div>
  <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100px; 
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Your `.content` div isn't going to show up because it has no height.

Comment: div .content contains numbers, to show that z-index for elements inside main container works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-index of the second `.main` div must be lower than that of the first div that contains the absolute div:

add a class to the second main

```
 <div class="main">
   <div class="content">11112222233</div>
   <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
<div class="main second"></div>
```

then use this style:

```
.second {z-index:99;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MNLbZ/4/)

Comment: OH MY GOD. Thank you, that was probably the last thing, where i was ready to find solution

Comment: z-index stacking issues are always a nightmare! glad I could help